# Vinegar Alternatives and rice combinations in making sushi rice

Tags: rice, sushi, vinegar

1. What are some of the alternatives in vinegar for making sushi rice? I know it's best to use rice vinegar, but has anyone ever tried it with white wine vinegar, or apple cider vinegar for example? Follow up on that question, would you put or more less vinegar?
2. What are some rice combinations that someone can use? I'm thinking for a next batch, I might do 80% sushi rice, 20% basmati, or 70% sushi rice and 30% arborio. Has anyone tried any such combinations, and if so how did it turn out?

Answer (score 7):

I have never made, but I have eaten [Arborio sushi](http://amandamc.blogspot.com/2005/10/are-you-ready-for-italian-sushi.html), with Italian flavors and here in DC I have had latin-flavored sushi.  It was all great.   The Arborio sushi seemed like plain Arborio rice to me.

The rice vinegar is sweet and less acid (4% versus 6%), so if you try different vinegars you may want to dilute it a bit first and then compare for sweetness.  Say you have 2 tablespoons of vinegar at 6%, then add add one tablespoon of water to it to bring it down to 4%.

Answer (score 5):

Further to Papin's excellent comment, you might also need to adjust for sweetness - so, e.g., if you decided to use white wine vinegar, as well as diluting it I'd add some sugar to taste.

With respect to your first question, there's a big difference between long-grain and short-grain rice. So Arborio is OK as a substitute if you want; however, Basmati grains won't stick together nearly as well, so your sushi will be more likely to fall apart if you take this option!

Comment: Oh, if you're /good/ at rolling up the sushi, and cook the basmati rice suitably (use slightly more water), it'll still work, just won't taste as good. (Specifically, it tastes bland)